# Relation between two different database tables into laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

Suppose i have two database into laravel:

```
 1. db_a
 2. db_b
```

`db_a` contains **users records** and `db_b` contains **posts of that users** and i want to establish relation between them. it is possible ? if yes then please write solution.

Comment: "if yes then please write solution." This is not how SO works. What have you done? do you have code examples? what solutions have you tried? have you searched if there's something simillar to *your* problem?

Comment: Also, just take a look at the docs. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#defining-models , search for "Database Connection"

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if databases are in same server and both the databases should have same database user with admin privileges.

```
emails1 = DB::connection('db1')->table('contacts_1')
         ->selectRaw('mail_address as email, date as created_at')->get();


$emails2 = DB::connection('db2')->table('contacts_2')
         ->select('email', 'created_at')->get();
```

for more information visit  [How to connect 2 different databases](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-connect-2-different-databases-and-join-2-tables-that-are-on-different-servers)

I hope it will help you...